# Workaround for ie10 background-position-x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

the body has a background (an svg) and I want to slide it to the left every time I click the background.

In the click handler i'm using

```
$('body').animate({'backgroundPositionX': nex+"em"},1500);
```

where nex gets incremented each time by 600.
and chrome and ff update the background-position-x just fine.  But on ie, it works in a very strange way. Or rather doesn't work in a very strange way.

when I hit f12, in ie10 the background position x stays the same always on the style tab but changes on the "computed" tab.  But even though you can see the computed value change, when you read background-position-x you don't get anything, so jquery animates from ZERO to the new location, instead of from the current location.

I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: The question about the `em`s you can easily test for yourself. Also, I see the problem on IE10, but the page doesn't show anything on Chrome and Mozilla. Just an empty cyan background.

Comment: I can't imagine why you wouldn't see it on chrome and mozilla.  what version are you using, if I may ask?

Comment: Chrome Version 32.0.1687.2 canary Aura and SeaMonkey 2.22 (Gecko  25.0), both under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, `background-position-x` is not supported in IE, which is really a bummer because  jquery's animate only works on single properties, not properties like `background-position: 5em 10em`.

The work around is to create a dummy var (here x) and animate that, and build the string each time, like so:

```
backposx=0;
function next_click() 
{
    $({x: 0}).animate({x: 600}, {
        duration: 1500,
        step: function(){
            $("#background").css("background-position",(backposx-~~this.x) + "em 0%");},
        complete:function(){backposx-=600;}
    });
}
```